# Regex to check for open tags

Tags: c#, regex

I am having trouble fabricating a Regex which will returns tags that are not self-closing. So I would want it to returns tags which are like so:

```
<blah>
```

But not tags which are like:

```
<blah/>
```

I have the following regex:

```
<(o|p)(.*?)>
```

Which is slightly simplified, ignore the rest it does what it is meant to do despite it's oddness. This will match all tags though while I need one that will ignore matches where the tag is self-closing.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
<(?:o|p)(?:[^"'>/]+|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>
```

Valid XHTML syntax is presumed.